# Getting "SessionNotCreatedException" when trying to set up selenium grid with Cucumber and TestNG

Tags: cucumber, testng, selenium-grid, cucumber-java

I am trying to setup Selenium grid with cucumber + TestNG.

While trying to run the tests I am getting *"org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."* however the browser is launching without launching application

I have written following code

```
public class DriverFactory {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
    private DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities;
    protected static ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();

    public DriverFactory() {
        desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.get();
    }

    public void initializeBrowser(String browserType) throws MalformedURLException {
        if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions));
            desiredCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
            desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        }
    }

    public WebDriver setAndGetDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            initializeBrowser("chrome");
            return getDriver();
        }

    }
```

My Step def code looks like this

```
`public FirstTestSteps(Hooks hooks) throws MalformedURLException {
        localHooks = hooks;
        localHooks.setup();
        driver = localHooks.getDriver();
        endpointData = ApiSetup.getData();
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        landingPage = new LandingPage(driver);
        cartPage = new CartPage(driver);
        checkoutInfoPage = new CheckoutInfoPage(driver);
    }

    @When("user navigates to portal")
    public void userNavigates() {
        loginPage.accessUrl();
    }`
```

I use following grid commands to launch hub and register node

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.10.0.jar hub
java -jar selenium-server-4.10.0.jar node --detect-drivers true --publish-events tcp://192.168.1.39:4442 --subscribe-events tcp://192.168.1.39:4443
java -jar selenium-server-4.10.0.jar node --port 5556 --detect-drivers true
```

Following is the complete stack trace

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'ADMINRG-77I9HE9', ip: '192.168.1.39'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.2.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, start-maximized], extensions: []}, platformName: Windows 10}]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, start-maximized], extensions: []}, platformName: Windows 10}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:549)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:154)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:134)
    at com.gridpro.hooks.DriverFactory.initializeBrowser(DriverFactory.java:49)
    at com.gridpro.hooks.DriverFactory.setAndGetDriver(DriverFactory.java:63)
    at com.gridpro.hooks.Hooks.setup(Hooks.java:32)
    at com.gridpro.definitions.FirstTestSteps.<init>(FirstTestSteps.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at io.cucumber.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:54)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:56)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.lambda$runScenario$1(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:132)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:129)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:37)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Dialect.lambda$bindAdditionalCommands$1(Dialect.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Dialect.bindAdditionalCommands(Dialect.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Dialect.access$100(Dialect.java:26)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Dialect$1.getCommandCodec(Dialect.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
    ... 50 more
```

[image: Blank page]

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error stacktrace?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium please check. On the UI blank page is getting opened with error stack trace

Comment: Is there a possibility to test your code with Java 8 or Java 11 instead of Java 18?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I had used some Java 18 features. Do you want me to try lower versions? But same version worked in other framework